# MongoDB increment nested document with upsert

Tags: mongodb, nested, upsert

Is it possible to execute a MongoDB query that would `increment` a field of a nested document and create that nested document when the document does not exist?

Example:

```
{
  id: ...
  nestedArray: [
    {kind: "foo", times: 10}
  ]
}
```

Let say I want to increment a field `nestedArray.$.times` where `kind: "bar"` but the `bar` does not exist in the array yet? So after executing query that would look something like

```
db.mycollection.update({id: "100", nestedArray:{$elemMatch: {kind: "bar"}}}, {$inc: {'nestedArray.$.times': 1}}, {upsert: true})
```

the document would look like this:

```
{
  id: ...
  nestedArray: [
    {kind: "foo", times: 10},
    {kind: "bar", times: 1}
  ]
}
```

And of course if the whole document is not found (not just the nested one), the one is automatically created.

Comment: Hi, I think you have the same problem as many: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-3326

Answer (score 1):

As a work around, this can be achieved with the help of two update queries,

**Query1**

```
db.mycollection.update(
  {id:"400","nestedArray.kind": "bar"},
  {$inc: {"nestedArray.$.times":1}}
)
```

This is a straight forward query and it increments the nestedArray.times value for nestedArray.kind is "bar". If the document is not found it does nothing.

**Query 2**

This query handles inserting new document / pushing into nested array in case matching document for id is present.

```
db.mycollection.update(
  {id:"400","nestedArray.kind": {$ne:"bar"}},
  {$push: {"nestedArray": {kind:"bar","times":1}}},
  {upsert:true}
)
```

This query searched for id in document where nestedArray.kind doesn't have bar value. If such a document is found, `{kind:"bar","times":1}` is pushed into nestedArray. If not found it created a new document with `{kind:"bar","times":1}` as the only value in nestedArray.

Comment: Query 2 creates a new `mycollection` document instead of creating `nestedArray` in the existing `mycollection` document.